# parse through JSON

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have the following JSON dump. I like to extract terms (e.g. "jobs") and counts (e.g. "46")

```
{u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'rows': [{u'f': [{u'v': u'jobs'}, {u'v': u'46'}]},      {u'f': [{u'v': u'employment'}, {u'v': u'24'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Employment'}, {u'v': u'20'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'donate furniture'}, {u'v': u'16'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'feeding the homeless'}, {u'v': u'16'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Perth stores'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'bed'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Jobs'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'food parcels'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'history'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Adherent'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'volunteer'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Historical society'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Donate furniture'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'pick up'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Careers'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'contact'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'helping with a funeral'}, {u'v': u'10'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Basketball'}, {u'v': u'10'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'email'}, {u'v': u'10'}]}], u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'2323', u'jobId': u'2323'}, u'jobComplete': True, u'totalRows': u'20', u'totalBytesProcessed': u'0', u'cacheHit': True, u'schema': {u'fields': [{u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'Query', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'Count', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}]}}
```

I like to print the terms and counts in a table format.

I have a function to do this:

```
print_two_cols(term1,term2)
```

however I am not sure how to iterate through the above JSON. I am using python 2.7.

Comment: that's not json. That's not anything CLOSE to json...

Comment: This is what I get from BigQuery

Comment: It's not a JSON string, but it looks like what you'd get if you parsed JSON with the json module.

Comment: It's a Python structure, that *perhaps* was parsed from JSON.

Comment: JSON is *just text* (that follows the rules on http://json.org). If you have a *Python object graph*, then that's what you have, not JSON - in such a case, make sure to *remove* all unnecessary talk of "JSON" from questions. The task then isn't to "parse the JSON", but to "iterate over" the objects according to some rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the `rows` key; each entry is a dictionary with a `f` key, containing dictionaries with `v` keys:

```
for row in result['rows']:
    job, count = (col['v'] for col in row['f'])
    print_two_cols(job, count)
```

Demo:

```
>>> result = {u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'rows': [{u'f': [{u'v': u'jobs'}, {u'v': u'46'}]},      {u'f': [{u'v': u'employment'}, {u'v': u'24'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Employment'}, {u'v': u'20'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'donate furniture'}, {u'v': u'16'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'feeding the homeless'}, {u'v': u'16'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Perth stores'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'bed'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Jobs'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'food parcels'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'history'}, {u'v': u'14'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Adherent'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'volunteer'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Historical society'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Donate furniture'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'pick up'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Careers'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'contact'}, {u'v': u'12'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'helping with a funeral'}, {u'v': u'10'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Basketball'}, {u'v': u'10'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'email'}, {u'v': u'10'}]}], u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'2323', u'jobId': u'2323'}, u'jobComplete': True, u'totalRows': u'20', u'totalBytesProcessed': u'0', u'cacheHit': True, u'schema': {u'fields': [{u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'Query', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'Count', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}]}}
>>> for row in result['rows']:
...     job, count = (col['v'] for col in row['f'])
...     print job, count
... 
jobs 46
employment 24
Employment 20
donate furniture 16
feeding the homeless 16
Perth stores 14
bed 14
Jobs 14
food parcels 14
history 14
Adherent 12
volunteer 12
Historical society 12
Donate furniture 12
pick up 12
Careers 12
contact 12
helping with a funeral 10
Basketball 10
email 10
```

Comment: Thanks man. Worked like a charm. I am new to python, did not know I could do that.